# UIView created from nib and autolayout not constrained to superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

In my last ios project I've been using a subview with these components and constraints:

```
V:|-5-[image(70)]-5-[label]-5-[button]-5-|
H:|-5-[label]-5-|
```

Everything works well if this subview is created in a `ViewController` with IB. 
Now I need to create this subview in some others `ViewControllers`, so I've thought that is a good moment to create a reusable custom subview from a nib instead of create it in each view controller. 
I've used these same components and constraints and I've set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

When I want to use this custom view this is what I'm doing in my superview:

```
PopupView *customView = [[PopupView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[customView setMessage:@"This is supposed to a be a large text. This is supposed to a be a large text"];
[self.view addSubview:customView];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[customView]|" 
                            options:0 
                            metrics:nil 
                          views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[customView]|" 
                            options:0 
                            metrics:nil 
                          views:viewsDictionary]];
```

The problem is: if the text for my label is too large, `customView` has a very large width (the needed to contain the label) and is not constrained to my superview. I thought that the last lines of my code would do that, but it seems that I'm missing something.

Do I need to do anything else so my `customView` is limited to my superview bounds?

**EDIT 1:**
I think is better if I put my code, this is a shorter version of my real code but it fails too:

PopupView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PopupView : UIView
{
    UILabel *messageLb;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *messageLb;

- (void) setMessage:(NSString *)message;

@end
```

PopupView.m

```
#import "PopupView.h"

@implementation PopupView

@synthesize messageLb = _messageLb;

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PopupView" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id object in objects)
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            view = object;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (view != nil)
    {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addSubview:view];
    }
}

- (void) setMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    [_messageLb setText:message];
}

@end
```

PopupView.xib

```
View
 |___ View (with constraints 0-0-0-0 to its superview)
        |___ label (with numberoflines 0 and constraints 5-5-5-5 to its superview)
```

**EDIT 2:** I've seen that I have some autolayout warnings I didn't see last night (I was too sleepy sorry).

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand,
refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145982e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' H:[UIView:0x14593210(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14592030 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x14593210]   (Names: '|':UITransitionView:0x14599db0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145bdc40 H:|-(0)-[PopupView:0x14592b60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14593210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145adeb0 H:[PopupView:0x14592b60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14593210 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x145a32c0 h=--& v=--& PopupView:0x14592b60.midX ==>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x145adeb0 H:[PopupView:0x14592b60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14593210 )>
```

I have these warnings with Vertical too.
I can see that due to this conflicts the rule that pin my view to the right margin is broken.
I've tried 2 things with no success:

- I set self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; in viewWillAppear method of the ViewController that uses this popup. >> Still the same warnings.
- I've changes the priority of my popup constraints. For example, this:

  ```
  NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView);
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
      @"H:|-0@1-[customView]-0@1-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
      @"V:|-0@1-[customView]-0@1-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
  ```

This removes all the vertical and horizontal warnings, but my popup is very large yet.

Comment: I finally found the solution. My problem was that I had no constraints between self (Popview) and their subviews. Once I set them everything is working. I've took the solution from [this post](http://sebastiancelis.com/2014/06/12/using-xibs-layout-custom-views/) I found.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on the custom view's textfield along with the `minimumFontSize` property would achieve the result you're looking for. Otherwise, using a `UITextView` could be useful due to it's ability to scroll through your content.

Comment: I've tried adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth with minimumFontSize with no success. I would prefer not to use UITextView. My UILabel has numberoflines 0 so it should use the number of lines needed instead of one very large line.

Comment: hmmm, and how about setting `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`?

Comment: also, seems I was looking at the ios6 docs for my first answer, from the 8.1 docs: `"In iOS 6 and earlier, this property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1."`

Comment: I was using NSLineBreakByWordWrapping. Regarding to adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, I don't really want my label to change its size but to have multiple lines. Anyway I've seen that I have some autolayout warnings so I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: I took a look at your 3rd edit, but what is odd is that you're still getting errors that relate to `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` which obviously refers to autoresizing masks. There's still something that's trying to use those masks. Moreover, there may be some issues with how you're setting up the nib and it's outlets, specifically I mean in reference to the nib's "owner".

Comment: Oh, and it's been a little while size I've looked into nibs, but check this out: [5 ways to load a nib](http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/)... it's just amazing. I also wrote 1/2 of a nib post a little while back on an old blog that may help [Xib/Nib](https://medium.com/@louistur/xib-nib-finally-a-tutorial-46a429a73adc)